# Django collectstatic not overwriting production files

Tags: python, django, heroku, amazon-s3

I have collectstatic --noinput running each time I push to Heroku. New files get copied, but old files with changes don't get overwritten. Deleting a file and pushing to heroku however, replaces that one specific file as expected.

How can I get collectstatic to overwrite files with changes?

Comment: What storage backend are you using for static files?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried collectfast? https://github.com/FundedByMe/collectfast.

This plugin is designed for S3, and it compares the MD5 of the files so it will upload changed files.

Comment: I was having the same issue and this worked for me. Just a side note, when I installed collectfast it wouldn't work without boto3 which wasn't installed with it. After installing boto3 everything worked as expected.